# Как во vue использовать сторонние модули

Tags: javascript, html, html5, vue.js

Пишет ощибку: что он не видит модуль
Html:

```html
<div id='vue'>
    <input v-model="input" placeholder="Name or id"><button v-on:click='pokemonGetInfo()'>ок</button>
    <p>Имя: {{ name }}</p>
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <img :src=image>
</div>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/pokeapi-js-wrapper/dist/index.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src='main.js'></script>
```

Js:

```js
const P = new Pokedex.Pokedex();

var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    input: '',
    name: '',
    image: ''
  },
  methods: {
    pokemonName() {
      P.getPokemonByName(this.input)
      .then(function (response) {
        this.name = response.name;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, неправильно дано имя функции у кнопки.
Во-вторых, старайся в хтмл всё в двойные ковычки оборачивать.
В-третьих, у меня такой ошибки не наблюдается. Но в апишку ходить не хочет.
Вот внизу работающий код.

```js
const P = new Pokedex.Pokedex();

var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    input: '',
    name: '',
    image: ''
  },
  methods: {
    pokemonName() {
      P.getPokemonByName(this.input)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.name = response.name;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src='https://unpkg.com/pokeapi-js-wrapper/dist/index.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='vue'>
    <input v-model="input" placeholder="Name or id">
    <button v-on:click="pokemonName">ок</button>
    <p>Имя: {{ name }}</p>
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <img :src="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил, все работает и мне пришёл ответ от сервера, вот правильный код

```js
const P = new Pokedex.Pokedex();

var vue = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    input: '',
    name: '',
    image: ''
  },
  methods: {
    pokemonName() {
      console.log(111);
      P.getPokemonByName(this.input)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id='vue'>
    <input v-model="input" placeholder="Name or id"><button v-on:click='pokemonName'>ок</button>
    <p>Имя: {{ name }}</p>
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    <img :src=image>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/pokeapi-js-wrapper/dist/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```